# Update existing app from Sencha to Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin

We have an app that is currently on the App Store, which was built using Sencha Touch, HTML etc, with some Objective C thrown in. Now we've re- written the whole app using Xamarin iOS and Objective C.

The structure of the two apps is completely different. How can the existing app be overwritten by the new app? Some clean up code needs to be executed if it is an upgrade. I only know how to obtain the version of the new app, not sure how to check anything on the old one(version, files etc).

I'd really appreciate any pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't check the version of the old app (unless you stored this already in the old version of the app in e.g. `NSUserDefaults` - the Xamarin-based app will be able to read those). It is a good practice to store it, so if you didn't do it, do it now, so that you will be able to detect future situations in which a migration is necessary.

If you stored something in files, e.g. in the Documents directory, you can read those files as well. Unless those files were in the temporary directory, they'll be there after the upgrade.

Comment: Turns out, the old app does have a version number associated with it. (Something the devs who worked on the old app just told me). But when I try to retrieve the old version using `NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey(new NSString("CFBundleShortVersionString")).ToString()` and even the object, it always returns null. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: This will only work if they stored it **explicitly** in the user defaults under the key `CFBundleShortVersionString`. This key is normally used in the Info.plist file, but you don't have access to that (as it's overwritten by your own version of the file).

Answer (score 0):

If you sign the app with the same security certificate (private key), and increment the version number (on the Xamarin side), it will be no problem.  You'll also need to keep the same App ID (Bundle ID) as the old app.  I've done this on one of my client's projects.

If you want to read files, etc, created by the old app, you'll need to write C# code to that, as you would have on the old app.

For example, the older Sencha Touch app we re-wrote with Xamarin used a SQLite database.  We wrote C# code using SQLite.Net to "convert" the old data into a new data format.  We only did this if we detected the existence of the old SQLite database, as we knew where the old app created the database file.